# multiple mutable references to disjoint parts of a slice using split_mut or similar

Tags: rust

Rust's [split_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_mut) function allows you to split a slice by a predicate. However, the predicate acts on elements of the slice. Example:

```
let mut v = [10, 40, 30, 20, 60, 50];

for group in v.split_mut(|num| *num % 3 == 0) {
    group[0] = 1;
}
assert_eq!(v, [1, 40, 30, 1, 60, 1]);
```

Can I split a slice in equal parts like this:

```
let mut v = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

and get

`&mut[1,2,3]` and `&mut[4,5,6]` and `&mut[7,8,9]`

in usch that all these mutables can exist in the same time without me having compilation problems? I want to have multiple mutable references to disjoint parts of a slice, **but the predicate should be on the index of the slice, not the elements**.

Comment: Try [chunks_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) ? [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0431780604ccfc071b2d8ebecc5e2b1)

Comment: Or two calls to [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut), depending on what exactly you want to do with the parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by **Jmb**

You can use [split_at_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) to divide a mutable slice into 2 non overlapping mutable slices.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    // Needs to be a multiple of v
    let number_of_parts = 5;

    let mid = v.len() / number_of_parts;

    let mut res = Vec::new();

    let mut ret = &mut v[..];

    for _ in 0..number_of_parts {
        let (head, tail) = ret.split_at_mut(mid);
        res.push(head);
        ret = tail;
    }

    println!("Parts: {:?}.", res);
}
```

As Suggested by **Õmer Erden**

You can use [chunks_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksMut.html) to iterate over a mutable slice an return non overlapping mutable slices.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    // Needs to be a multiple of v
    let number_of_parts = 5;

    let mid = v.len() / number_of_parts;

    let mut res = Vec::new();

    for chunk in v.chunks_mut(mid) {
        res.push(chunk);
    }

    println!("Parts: {:?}.", res);
}
```